# Rate limit API requests in node.js

Tags: node.js, api

First off, I'm new here, so please...be gentle...I've been teaching myself node.js over the last few months, mostly with the desire to scrape a bunch of data from the FlightAware website API.

I am trying to request from their site a list of flights for aircraft, here is what I have so far.

```
var aircraft = [array,of,aircraft,tail,numbers]   

for (i=0; i < aircraft.length; i++) {

    faGetFlight(aircraft[i],function doneLookup(data) {

        dbUpdateFlight(collectionName, data)
    })
}
```

This code works, but as soon as there is more than 10 aircraft in the list, it fails, because is sending more than 10 API requests in a minute.  What are some easy/straightforward ways to slow this down a little.  I would like to send about 50-60 API requests total each time this runs, so I need it spaced over 5-6 minutes.   The faGetFlight() function uses the 'request' module. I've tried the request-rate-limit module instead of the request module, but I can't seem to make it work. I don't think the authorization works properly with the request-rate-limiter module.  Getting an error about anonymous user. For what it's work, it works with just the request module instead, but I run into the rate limit issues.

Here is my faGetFlight() code.

```
var RateLimiter = require('request-rate-limiter');
const REQS_PER_MIN = 10; // that's 25 per second
var limiter = new RateLimiter(REQS_PER_MIN);

//API Variables //
var apiUrl = 'url'
var apiEndpoint = 'endpoint'
var apiAuth = 'apikey'
var apiExtData = 0
var apiHowMany = 15         //Number of results to request.                                               

var options = { method: 'GET',
    url: apiUrl + apiEndpoint,
    qs: { ident: acIdent
        },

        headers: 
    { 
        Authorization: apiAuth }                  
    };

        limiter.request(options, function doneDownload(error, response, body) {         
            if (error) throw new error(error);
            callback(body)
        });

}
```

Sorry if this isn't clear...it's my first post!

Comment: You did great for your first post, and welcome to SO. Are you getting an error message and if so on what line?

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence :)   The API was kicking an error back.  I was executing too many requests per minute.

Comment: You could use [rate-limiter-flexible](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#third-party-api-crawler-bot-rate-limiting) node.js package for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a naive implementation using functions and a simple `setTimeout`.

See:

```
var aircrafts = [array,of,aircraft,tail,numbers]; 
var REQS_PER_MIN = 10;
var MAX_AMOUNT_REQUESTS = 100;
var timeout = (1 / REQS_PER_MIN) * 60 * 1000;

processAircraft(0);

function processAircraft(index){
    if(index >= MAX_AMOUNT_REQUESTS)
        return console.log("All done!");
    //On start of function, schedule next processing in "timeout" ms
    setTimeout(function(){
        processAircraft(index+1);
    }, timeout);

    faGetFlight(aircrafts[index], function doneLookup(data) {
        dbUpdateFlight(collectionName, data)
    })
}
```

Comment: Yup, that got it.  Thanks!  Seems so simple when I see it written out!.

Comment: No problem! Fly safe.

Comment: Sorry, one issue i just noticed...it's looping one to many times and kicks an "undefined" error out at the end.

Comment: I edited the code to `>=` instead of `>` in `if(index >= MAX_AMOUNT_REQUESTS)` about 30 minutes ago, do you have it?

Comment: I see it now, didn't notice that.  Thx